# Submenu in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, menu, submenu

I have menu already ang now i create submenu and i need the simillar effect to menu on this site: http://www.lexus-polska.pl/

```
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Item</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Submenu</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Submenu</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Item</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Submenu</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Submenu</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
</ul>
```

Structure: http://jsfiddle.net/dc6e4szd/

Menu functions:

- submenu is visible only when parent menu is clicked
- background of the submenu must be 100% width

Please, show me any directions how i need to style it or use some script, because im stuck on it

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress, by default, gives all the `<li>`'s with sub items a class of "menu-item-has-children". We can use jQuery to target that class and do things like add a click function to show and hide its children.

First, we need to hide the sub-menu with CSS.

```
.sub-menu {display: none;}
```

Then with jQuery, we add a click function and use `.slideToggle` to change the style to `display: block;` and add a slide open/closed effect when the parent `<li>`'s `<a>` is clicked.

```
$('.menu-item-has-children').children('a').on('click', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  $(this).next('.sub-menu').slideToggle(100).end().parent('.menu-item-has-children').siblings('.menu-item-has-children').children('a').next('.sub-menu').slideUp(100);
});
```

Here is my [Codepen example](http://codepen.io/JonDCarey/pen/raQmZW).

Here is the [slideToggle documentation](http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/).